# Android Studio project with Github

Tags: android

I am currently working on a Android Studio Project that I am sharing with other team mates. In order to do this we are using GitHub to share the Project.

I tried using the option "Check out project from Version Control". However one I successfully download and open the Project I get "Error Loading Project: Cannot load 2 modules", being two .iml files, one which is the app.iml. This prevents me from accessing the app folder from the project, hence I cannot work with it in Android Studio.

I have tried downloading it from our GitHub repository directly and opening it with Android Studio, however I get the same error.

Can anyone help me figure out how to successfully run a GitHub shared Android Studio project?

I am running this on Windows 10.

Comment: The iml files shouldn't be committed inside the repo because they have local path. Try to remove these file and build with gradle your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.iml files are the local configuration of the IDE, you and other team members should add it to .gitignore.

Also you can deleted them any time you want , and select **Build Project** from the **Run** menu. They will be generared again.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `.iml` files are specific for local configurations. You have to remove them manually from the repository and not push them. I recommend to you to use a `.gitignore` file that can be either global or a project file with some classic Android excludes:

```
#built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Windows thumbnail db
Thumbs.db

# OSX files
.DS_Store

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Android Studio
*.iml
.idea
#.idea/workspace.xml - remove # and delete .idea if it better suit your needs.
.gradle
build/

#NDK
obj/
```